# JAVASCRIPT: does Arrays constructor automatically have a variable called arguments?

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

So, in the following code, I'm wondering why the "arguments" in the apply method automatically gets populated with the arguments in the array constructor.

```
function SpecialArray(){
    var values = new Array();
    values.push.apply(values, arguments);  // does arguments descend automatically from the constructor?
    values.toPipedString = function() {
    return this.join("|");
    };

    return values;
}

var colors = new SpecialArray("red","blue","green");
console.log(colors.toPipedString()); // prints: "red|blue|green"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not special about a constructor or about arrays.

Inside of every function you can access its [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) that way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, I think, is that the "arguments" special object belongs to the SpecialArray function's context.  if arguments was called in a push() in the toPipedString() function expression, then it would refer to the local context of that function.